# Geocell & Google App Engine Spatial Query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, geospatial

```
lat = json.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(i).getDouble("lat");
lon = json.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(i).getDouble("lon");
Point p = new Point(lat, lon);
List<String> cells = GeocellManager.generateGeoCell(p);
```

Using upper code, i can get a cells like below.

[9, 9f, 9ff, 9fff, 9fffe, 9fffe1, 9fffe13, 9fffe136, 9fffe1364, 9fffe1364f, 9fffe1364fb, 9fffe1364fb7, 9fffe1364fb76]

And at the last element "9fffe1364fb76", how big that element indicate?

now i will tell you about what i know.

the earth size of earth is 510,072,000Km^2.

and the element "9" means 510,070,000km^2/16.

and the element "9f" means (510,070,000km^2)/(16^2)

..
the last element "9fffe1364fb76" means (510,070,000km^2)/(16^13).

this is what i know about geocell. is this right?

otherwise, please tell me truth...zzZ

Comment: Maybe add the tag java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Geocells divide the [-90,90] x [-180,180] latitude/longitude space in parts. A geocell string of length 1 divides this area in 16 parts, and each of the two dimensions in 4 parts. Each subsecutive character divides each dimension by 4 again. With a string of length 13 (the longest one), each dimension has been divided 13 times with a factor of 4, or 4^13 = 67108864. So the [-90,90] latitude interval is divided into 180 / 67108864 = 2.68220901 E-6 degrees, and the [-180,180] longitude interval interval is divided into 360 / 67108864 = 5.36441802 E-6 degrees.

How large this is in terms of distance depends on where you are on Earth, because the same amount of degrees translates to a different longitudinal distance on different latitudes. On the equator, one degree equals 111.319 km in both directions, so the highest resolution geocell on the equator measures 0.597m x 0.2985m, with corresponds to a surface area of roughly 0.18 m^2.

At the pole, the longitudinal length shrinks to zero. In between, at a latitude of 60 degrees, the geocell is square and has a dimension of 0.2985m x 0.2985m, with a surface area of 0.089 m^2.